# How can i remove selected document in an Angular page from Mongo DB?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, scala

i have a project in Angular js with Reactivemongo and i am trying to remove a document from a collection. I have written my Scala controller:

```
def delete = Action.async {
collection.remove(BSONDocument("_id" -> _id)).map(_ => Ok(s"User Deleted")).recover { case _ => InternalServerError }}
```

And my Angular controller is below:

```
controller("GuestCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){

      $http.get("/guest/all").success(function(res){
      console.log(res);
      $scope.guests = res;
       });


       $scope.deleteGuest = function(guest){
       console.log(guest);
       $http.post("/guest/delete", guest).success(function(result){

       });
       };




       $scope.registerGuest = function(newguest){
        console.log(newguest);
        $http.post("/guest/create", newguest).success(function(result){
        $scope.newguest = result;
        });
        };


        }]);
```

my angular html page is:

```
<div class= "col-md-5">
    <ul class="guests">
        <li ng-repeat="guest in guests ">

        <h1>{{guest.name}}</h1>

        <p>{{guest.address}}</p>

        <input type="submit" value="Delete" ng-click="deleteGuest(guest)">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" ng-click="updateGuest(guest)">
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

If anyone has any idea how i can make an update and delete, pls help me out!I wrote a delete function in the Angular controller but it does not work.

Comment: Please clarify WHAT does not work. Are there errors? Is the reset send, does the request reach the controller?

Comment: When i click on deleteGuest, right now nothing happens because i am not sure how to go about implementing it. I can get all guests and create new guests just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this...updated my angular controller to

```
 $scope.deleteGuest = function(guest){
       console.log(guest);
       $http.post("/guest/delete", {guest: guest}).success(function(result){

       });
       };
```

and my Scala controller to

```
def delete = Action.async(parse.json){ request =>
val delGuest = ( request.body \ "guest").as[Guest]
 println (delGuest)

guestCollection.remove(Json.obj("_id" -> delGuest._id)).map(_ => Ok).recover { case _ => InternalServerError }}
```

Went on to do a post request.